# grep search for "--" or "-->" gives unrecognised or invalid option

Tags: grep

Trying to use grep on linux to search through some php files:

`grep -R '-->' .` gives `Unrecognised option '-->'`

`grep -R '->' .` gives `invalid option -- '>'`

How can I search for either `-->` or `->`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, dashes start options, so it's only natural `grep` tries to interpret that as one. You'd have the same problem if searching for `-R`.

Use `-e`:

> `-e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN`
>
> Use  *PATTERN*  as  the  pattern.   If  this option is used multiple times or is combined with the `-f` (`--file`) option, search for all patterns given.  This
>       option can be used to protect a pattern beginning with “`-`”.

Answer (score 19):

Use `--` to indicate that remaining arguments are not options:

```
grep -R -- '-->' .
```

Comment: Thanks. I had been struggling with this for years, always confused about why the problem also exists when you use the -F, --fixed-strings flag.

Comment: Cann't express how much appreciate!